What is the difference between OSAllocatedUnfairLock's withLock and withLockUnchecked functions?
OSAllocatedUnfairLock has two different methods for executing a block of code with the lock held: withLock() and withLockUnchecked(). The only difference between the two is that the former has the closure and return type marked as Sendable. withLockUnchecked() has a comment (that is for reasons I do not understand not visible in the documentation) saying:
    ///  This method does not enforce sendability requirement
    ///  on closure body and its return type.
    ///  The caller of this method is responsible for ensuring references
    ///   to non-sendables from closure uphold the Sendability contract.

What I do not understand here is why Sendable conformance would be needed. These function should call this block synchronously in the same context, and return the return value through a normal function return. None of this should require the types to be Sendable. This seems to be supported by this paragraph of the documentation for OSAllocatedUnfairLock:
/// This lock must be unlocked from the same thread that locked it.  As such, it
/// is unsafe to use `lock()` / `unlock()` across an `await` suspension point.
/// Instead, use `withLock` to enforce that the lock is only held within
/// a synchronous scope.

So, why does this Sendable requirement exist, and in practice, if I did want to use withLockUnchecked, how would I "uphold the Sendability contract"?
To summarise the question in a more concise way: Is there an example where using withLockUnchecked() would actually cause a problem, and using withLock() instead would catch that problem?

That doesn't really answer this question, I don't think? In this case, the Sendable conformance is on the closure passed to withLock, and on the return type from that closure.

Ah, I thought it was on the type itself. Ignore me :)

There's a general problem with closure parameters: a closure can potentially capture non-sendable values. Closures are reference types, like classes. Thus, running a closure in different isolation domains may potentially race. Due to this, a closure parameter in any function should be declared @Sendable. Now, closures may not explicitly be marked as sendable, but actually might be safe (when it will be used only once). Thus, we have a somewhat relaxed modifier sending which can be used instead of @Sendable. IMHO, withLock should use sending instead of @Sendable.

Consider the following code:
actor S {
    let state = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: 1)

    var otherValue: Int = 0

    func f() {
        state.withLock { value in
            value += 1
            otherValue += 1  // Actor-isolated property 'otherValue' can not be mutated from a Sendable closure
        }
    }
}

This code is invalid, and the compiler will complain that it's invalid with a hard error. The closure is not isolated to the actor. It's not currently possible to do that in Swift. See SE-0431 for future changes that could make that possible, but it's not possible today.
I could make this even more egregious, to make it a bit clearer how this could go sideways:
func f() {
    state.withLock { value in
        value += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.otherValue += 1  // Actor-isolated property 'otherValue' can not be mutated from the main actor; this is an error in Swift 6
        }
    }
}

I think we can all agree that this is completely wrong and breaks concurrency safety, but it also only generates a warning under strict concurrency.
Now consider this code in the same actor, which does not do anything wrong:
func f() {
    let c: (inout Int) -> Void = { value in value += 1 }
    state.withLock(c) // Converting non-sendable function value to '@Sendable (inout Int) throws -> Void' may introduce data races
}

Nonetheless, there is a warning generated that this might generate a data race because I did not mark c as Sendable. Marking c as Sendable will fix this, but that may not be possible for existing code.
If, however, I know that c really is Sendable, even though I can't mark it that way, I can use withLockUnchecked to avoid the warning. But it is up to me to enforce the rules and not do things like modify actor isolated properties.
Similar situations occur if we replace actor here with struct, and make f mutating. Since the entire struct may be copied, this can quickly become unsafe. The Unchecked variant exists for those cases where I know for certain that doesn't happen.

I'm not sure I quite follow this answer here. For instance, to me, the first example is perfectly valid code, because the closure is non-escaping and will be executed entirely synchronously, so it should be trivial to see that it is still isolated to the same actor, shouldn't it? The only reason it throws an error is that the closure is marked @Sendable, and my question was why it is marked like that in the first place.

Like, in summary, is there any reason, in all of those examples, to not just use withLockUnchecked instead of withLock? Is the Sendable conformances in withLock actually contributing anything, or are they just making things harder, like preventing the first example from working? Is there an example of using withLockUnchecked that causes a problem, where withLock would prevent it?

Also, why is the return type of the closure also marked Sendable? That seems even more unnecessary.

My example with DispatchQueue.main.async is an example where withLockUnchecked would cause a problem that withLock would prevent.

The first example asserts that "the closure is not isolated to the actor", but… is that really the case here, since it is a non-escaping synchronous closure inside a function that is isolated to the actor?

I would expect the second example to fail with both withLockUnchecked and withLock? Does it not?

I tested it, and the compiler complains in both cases, whether I use withLockUnchecked or withLock. So that does not seem to be a justification for the need for Sendable here.

Also, for the first example, the only reason the closure is not isolated to the actor is BECAUSE it is @Sendable. If it were not sendable, like when using withLockUnchecked, then it is isolated to the actor, and the code works without complaints from the compiler.

That's not correct. Being non-Sendable does not make the closure isolated to the actor. We hope at some point that will be true, but today it is not. The closure could have { @MainActor in ... at the beginning. Being non-Sendable just means it's not safe to pass the closure between contexts. It doesn't mean the closure is isolated to a context. I think you're confusing "I can see this is ok" with "the compiler is currently capable of proving this is ok."

But in this case, both seem to be true, don't they? It is clearly OK, because the closure is not passed between contexts, and the compiler thinks it is OK? I still don't see why the closure would need to be Sendable.
